# How to create fixed layout in Android

Tags: java, android

My activity has spinners, which supposedly should be in the centre. Relative to the spinners positions, buttons and labels are placed.

Another activity has 8 buttons in which certain values will be displayed. I have used a RelativeLayout in all activities. My app works well on my Moto G, but on bigger devices, the alignment of all the buttons and spinners changes.

I want to fix that issue.

Comment: so give a fixed size or? 100dp? 300dp?

Comment: Give a size to what ??

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question a bit. You could further improve it by adding a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may want to point out in the question that you want a fixed layout, in addition to having this in the title. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the case of `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

This will make the element always stick to the center of the device irrespective of the size of the device. Try it..

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnSample" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```